# pandas merge not using sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have these two dataframe.

jj1a

```
,driver_trip,prob,rprob
0,1_3,1.0,1
1,1_5,1.0,1
2,1_9,1.0,1
3,1_11,1.0,1
4,1_12,1.0,1
5,1_15,1.0,1
6,1_17,1.0,1
7,1_31,1.0,1
8,1_33,1.0,1
9,1_43,1.0,1
```

jjra

```
,driver_trip,prob,rprob
0,1_1,1.0,0.0
1,1_2,1.0,0.0
2,1_3,1.0,0.0
3,1_4,1.0,0.0
4,1_5,1.0,0.0
5,1_6,1.0,0.0
6,1_7,1.0,0.0
7,1_8,1.0,0.0
8,1_9,1.0,0.0
9,1_10,1.0,0.0
```

This is my desired output:

rrss3

```
,driver_trip,prob
0,1_1,0.0
1,1_10,0.0
2,1_2,0.0
3,1_3,1.0
4,1_4,0.0
5,1_5,1.0
6,1_6,0.0
7,1_7,0.0
8,1_8,0.0
9,1_9,1.0
```

I manage to do it but its clumsy. Look for a better solution.

my sol:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandasql import sqldf
```

kkm=pd.merge(jj1a, jjra, left_on='driver_trip', right_on='driver_trip', how='right',sort=True)

qqq="""select driver_trip ,rprob_x prob from kkm where rprob_x=1 and rprob_y=0 union select driver_trip ,rprob_y prob from kkm where rprob_x is null and rprob_y = 0;"""

rrss3 = sqldf(qqq,locals())

I intend to not use sqldf just use merge but cant figure it out..
I get some example for filtering bull after the merge but not sure whats next..

```
kkm[pd.isnull(kkm).any(axis=1)]
kkm[-pd.isnull(kkm).any(axis=1)]
```

Also is it possible to to sort by the order of driver_trip column
e.g. 2_1 should go before 100_1 but I dont know how to do this. I can do it in oracle sql tho.

```
with mk3 as (
select '1_1' driver_trip, 1 prob from dual
union
select '2_100' driver_trip ,0 prob from dual
union
select '100_1' driver_trip, 0 prob from dual
union
select '2_2' driver_trip, 0 prob from dual
union
select '1_100' driver_trip,1 prob from dual
)
  select driver_trip,prob
 from mk3 order by (
 to_number(substr(driver_trip,1,instr(driver_trip,'_')-1))
  ),to_number(substr(driver_trip,instr(driver_trip,'_')+1,length(driver_trip)-instr(driver_trip,'_')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carry on with the `merge` based solution.
You can multiply the `prob` values.

```
rrss3 = pd.merge(jj1a, jjra, on='driver_trip', how='right').fillna(0.0)
rrss3['prob'] = rrss3['prob_x'] * rrss3['prob_y']
rrss3[['driver_trip', 'prob']].sort('driver_trip')
```

Or you can use `numpy.where`

```
rrss3 = pd.merge(jj1a, jjra, on='driver_trip', how='right').fillna(0.0)
rrss3['prob'] = np.where((rrss3['prob_x'] == 1) & (rrss3['prob_y'] == 1), 1, 0)
rrss3[['driver_trip', 'prob']].sort('driver_trip')
```